# which situation to not use pg and use mingo instead

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

I have experience in pg, but I never try mongo.
In pg, there is JSON datatype that support nosql and the current pg version is quite fast.

And pg can also support relation, and transaction too which is quite important features.

My question is which situation to not use pg and use mingo instead.

Thanks so much.

Comment: If you're curious about the general aspect of this question, well, just try it. If you have a specific case in mind, you have to explain it in your question.

Comment: almost never because postgresql JSONB outperforms mongo http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-plus-edb-blog/marc-linster/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-new-developer-reality

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It look like pg can beat Mongo in any situation (see link that e4c5 suggested).

Thanks everyone, from your feedback.